# How can you remove empty or blank lines from a text file using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I would like to remove all blank lines (lines that just have some number of spaces and a newline character) from a list of files using MSBuild.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I recognize that I could write a MSBuild plug in C# or VB.NET that will do this using simple Regex replacement, but would prefer a solution that doesn't need me to do this.

If there's a open source MSBuild plugin that does this - I'd welcome that solution as well.

Comment: Is an inline task out of the question?

Comment: Not at all --- I don't think I'm familiar with this --- would this be the ability to write C# in the MSBuild script file itself to accomplish this?

Comment: Yup, its basically a task (like you nixed), but inline. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx

Comment: Apply [second RegEx from accepted solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643113/regex-to-strip-comments-and-multi-line-comments-and-empty-lines) on [FileUpdate task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026436/change-only-revision-number-in-assemblyinfo-cs-with-msbuild-fileupdate-task). (My answer was converted to comment)

Comment: I'm getting an error from FileUpdate saying that ReplacementText can't be null (empty string for the replacement)

Answer (score 3):

@Ludwo is right, you have to take into account white-space characters. Moreover to replace any text with empty string you need to use [`ReplacementTextEmpty` property](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/1.5.0.235/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/FileUpdate.cs#L156) instead of passing empty string to `ReplacementText` property. So, the following target should solve the problem:

```xml
<Target Name="Minify">
  <ItemGroup>
    <File Include="**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <FileUpdate
    Files="@(File)"
    Regex="(\n\s*\n)+"
    Multiline="False"
    ReplacementTextEmpty="True"/>
</Target>
```

You just need to call the target via MSBuild:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /t:Minify
```